# Документация по C++

Tags: документация, c++

Кто-нибудь сможет мне подсказать документацию по c++?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Господа все гораздо релевантней - [с++](http://www.cplusplus.com) - сам по нему учился и до сих пор нахожу ответы на мои вопросы

Answer (score 0):

[Справочные материалы по Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ty9hx077.aspx)

> Ссылки, приведенные ниже, указывают на разделы, содержащие сведения по Visual C++.

Это Visual C++, но для начала кроссплатформенность не существенна.

Answer (score 0):

Легко. Идем [сюда](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/) и качаем pdf. Но  есть одна особенность - черновики стандарта - бесплатны, а чистовики - за отдельную плату. Но при особой усидчивости, можно найти за приемлемую плату.

Comment: При некоторой усидчивости можно найти за бесплатно ))))

Comment: ISO копирасты несчастные. Столмана на них нету.

Comment: я тоже никогда не понимал фишки **продажи** стандартов. по идее они должны бы быть заинтересованы в получении копий как можно большим количеством людей.

Comment: @karmadro4 А на что они жить будут?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.kuzbass.ru:8086/docs/isocpp/ - спецификация С++ 98 года.
Новый стандарт пока платный - http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=50372 (хотя возможно на торрентах где-то есть).
Есть еще обзор возможностей, введенных в новом стандарте - http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/hh852594.aspx